# Meaning of the word "overtime" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context

It is from this [video](https://youtu.be/NKdQRTkQE4U). It is at around 6 minute. Here is the context:

> This happens because when blood and other fluids block your circulation the heart is forced in **overtime**.

The word *overtime* has a few meanings according to [The Oxford Dictionary](https://youtu.be/NKdQRTkQE4U), and it seems to me none fits.

Comment: Note: I really, really wouldn't take medical advice from whoever phrased that sentence.

Comment: I think the narrator "misspoke". What he *should* have said *(meant* to say?) was *the heart is forced into **overdrive*** (note that he clearly says ***into***, not ***in***. Google Books has well over 2000 written instances of [*heart went into overdrive*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22heart+went+into+overdrive%22), but just 54 instances of [*heart went into overtime*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22heart+went+into+overtime%22) (which I don't think is a sensible figurative usage anyway, quite apart from the fact that it's not the "idiomatic standard").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When certain employers require their workers to do more than 40 hours in a week, they are required to pay a higher wage, referred to as **overtime**.  Employers do not like to pay 1.5 or 2 times the usual wage, so in most cases overtime happens only during extraordinary circumstances: when a big, time-sensitive job must be completed right away or when the business is short-staffed and has not been able to hire workers to meet its needs.

There is a sense, then, that workers doing overtime and overworked and frantically trying to get the job done to keep the business from going under. The word is often used in a more general context. When your circulation is blocked, the heart must work at a frantic pace, with an unusual load.  It has to work *overtime* to keep you alive.

Comment: It seems a bit OTT to actually vote this *down*, but I don't see much point in "explaining" how this inappropriate metaphor is *supposed* to work. Apart from anything else, I don't think ***overtime*** particularly alludes to ***hard / energetic work*** in the cited context - the heart is ***always*** working anyway, so it's a bit meaningless to talk about it spending ***more time*** working.

Comment: We often use 'working overtime' to mean 'working harder than usual', especially when we are not talking literally about working at a paid job. Since my mother became sick, I have been working overtime looking after my little brother and studying.